# Update Datagridview From Another Form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

First I should say i saw this link :

[How to refresh datagridview when closing child form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395624/how-to-refresh-datagridview-when-closing-child-form)

And i did like this:
(i have datagridview in Form1)
**Form1:**

```
                public void FillDataGridView(DataTable dt1)
            {
                    bindingSource1.DataSource = dt1;
                    bindingSource1.ResetBindings(false);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
                    //here i checked number of rows of dt1 and it shows the correct value
            }
```

**Form2:**

```
           SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"My connection string");
            private Form1 Handled_frm1;
            public Form2(Form1 frm1)
            {
                    InitializeComponent();

                Handled_frm1 = frm1;
            }

               private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                     {
                        dt.Clear();
                        using (SqlCommand cmd =cnn.CreateCommand())
                        {
                            if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                            {
                                cnn.Open();
                            }
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Connection = cnn;
                            cmd.CommandText = "spSearchCustomerByName";
                            SqlParameter inparam1 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textbox1.Text);
                            inparam1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                            dap.SelectCommand = cmd;
                            dap.Fill(dt);

                            Handled_frm1.FillDataGridView(dt);
                        }
```

But the value Of Datagridview does not change!

**Edited:**

I wanted to test that if i can clear datagrid view or not,so i changed FillDataGridView like this :

```
                public void FillDataGridView(DataTable dt1)
            {
                    dt.Clear();
                    dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                    dataGridView1.Refresh();
            }
```

but it does not clear datagridview1!!!

Comment: Your code does not show how the data underlying the second form relates to the data table you use in the first form. Where is, e.g., cnn initialized?

Comment: Probably a similar type SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947818/updating-datagridview-from-another-form-using-backgroundworker ?

Comment: @JohnB:cnn initialized in Form2,i edited my question

Comment: `Handled_frm1 = fromSearchNewCustomer;` should be `Handled_frm1 = frm1;`, as otherwise you're just discarding the reference to the parent form. Then when you call `Handled_frm1.FillDataGridView` it resolves to the correct form.

Comment: i posted here with mistake,i updated my question

Comment: Still another mistake? `Handled_frm_search_new_customer.FillDataGridView` should be `Handled_frm1.FillDataGridView`, should it not? Also, what errors (if any) are you getting?

Comment: ops i edited my question again,sorry.i dont get any error,datagridview rows does not change!but when i checked count of rows where i commented,it shows the correct count!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Used mistakenly an incorrect instance of Form1!!

in form1,there is a button that when click it,it shows form2.i wrote this code in click event of it:

```
Form1 frm1=new Form1();
Form2 frm2=new Form2(frm1);
```

and this was incorrect,because i made additional instance of Form1.

And I Change the code like this:

```
Form2 frm2=new Form2(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a BindingSource, like described in the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource

I think setting DataSource directly doesn't cause the DataGridView to re-bind, whereas BindingSource takes care of that.

Comment: Binding to DataSource automatically sets up a binding context between the control and the object in question, so your statement is false. However, attaching to a BindingSource does allow for a bit more flexibility, so still valid.

Comment: i used binding source according to your link,but it didnt solved my problem,please see my edited post that i added binding source

Comment: Try calling "bindingSource1.ResetBindings(false);" after setting BindingSource.DataSource. Also, no need to set DataGridView.DataSource every time, just once in the beginning.

Comment: i did it,but it didnt solved!,i added datagridview datasource one time