# Updating datagridview from another form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a datagridview at a certain form. In that form there is a add and update button which will accept details and when the finish button is click, I want to update the gridview. But it seems I cannot accomplish this since I'm adding/updating details from another form.

First Form (Bind data, go to update/add button form):

```
Private Sub bindStudentsData()
    Dim db As New Database()

    DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
    DataGridView1.DataSource = New BindingSource(db.getStudentList(), Nothing)

End Sub


Private Sub addBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addBtn.Click
    Dim sf As New StudentForm()
    sf.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub updateBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles updateBtn.Click
    Dim sid As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("studentid").Value

    Dim sf As New StudentForm(sid)
    sf.Show()
End Sub
```

*By using .show() the previous form stays open and opens another form

Then after entering the details and click finish
Second Form:

```
Private Sub doneBtm_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles doneBtm.Click
    Dim db As New Database()
    If type Is "add" Then
        'go to add
        MsgBox(type)
    Else
        'go to update
        db.updateStudentDetails(sid, astudentnumberText.Text, afirstnameText.Text, 
                     _alastnameText.Text, amiddlenameText.Text, asectionText.Text)
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

I need to rebind the datagridview in my first form after clicking done button on the second form. How could I do that? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887948/update-datagridview-from-another-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest and better method is to simply use `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`. It blocks your current form until you close the newly opened form. Then Call your `bindStudentsData()`. No more changes

```
Private Sub updateBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles updateBtn.Click
    Dim sid As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("studentid").Value    
    Dim sf As New StudentForm(sid)
    sf.ShowDialog()
    bindStudentsData()
End Sub
```

---

**Second Method** (which you want). Complex but if you are not willing to use ShowDialog at any Cost

Make your `bindStudentsData()` public and make current form, the `Owner` of next Form

```
Private Sub updateBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles updateBtn.Click
    Dim sid As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("studentid").Value    
    Dim sf As New StudentForm(sid)
    sf.Owner = Me
    sf.Show()
    bindStudentsData();
End Sub
```

Now you can access first form in second form by using `Owner` and hence you can call methods of first form as well. Just call `bindStudentsData()` before closing second form

```
Private Sub doneBtm_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles doneBtm.Click
    Dim db As New Database()
    If type Is "add" Then
        'go to add
        MsgBox(type)
    Else
        'go to update
         db.updateStudentDetails(sid, astudentnumberText.Text, afirstnameText.Text, 
                 _alastnameText.Text, amiddlenameText.Text, asectionText.Text)
         Dim f1 As Form1 = TryCast(Me.Owner, Form1);
         // I have supposed that your first Form is Form1
         f1.bindStudentsData()
         Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the two choices, and I use the second suggestion but in a different manner. Still it gave me and idea of passing the existing instance of the form to the next form so I can access the methods at the second form. THanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you finish, you could save your data in db, then call back the form you want to refresh. And the binding will be refresh with the updated/new data in it...

From the comment of @kush, if you wish to close the second form after work is done, you can add a script tag in Response witch close the page.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since the question was posted but I use another solution and some people may find it usefull.

In the form1, I open my second form :

```
Dim frm As New Form1()
frm.ShowDialog()
```

Then, in the second form, when I press the **OK button** I write :

```
DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
Me.Close()
```

Finally, in form1, I add these lines under `frm.ShowDialog()`:

```
If frm.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    reaload_DTGV()
End If
```

With this method, you can **keep your datagridview's methods from form1 to Private**.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I did it using databindingsource:

In my button edit in form1:

```
edit_product.Show()
edit_product.Item_numTextBox.Text = Item_numTextBox.Text
Me.Close()
```

Then in my form2:

```
Private Sub Item_numTextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Item_numTextBox.TextChanged
      InventoryBindingSource.Filter = "[item_num] like '%' + '" & Item_numTextBox.Text & "' + '%'"
End Sub
```