# pass datagridview from one form to another c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i want to pass my datagridview from form1 to form2.I've tried with constructor but without result, datagridview in second form is empty.
Could someone help me here, i'm stacked for hours.I dont use sql and i dont need to use dataTable.Here is my code:

I fill datagridview3 on cellClick event of datagridview2.
When I click on dayagridview2 cellClick_event my datagridview3 is filled with this method:

```
 private void dataGridView2_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataD d = new DataD();
        d.Mat(dataGridView1,dataGridView2,dataGridView3);

    }
```

Here is method from which is filled dataGridView3:

```
   public void Mat(DataGridView dataGridView1, DataGridView dataGridView2,DataGridView dataGridView3)
    {
        Named n = new Named();

        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView2.SelectedCells)
        {
            IList<String> lista = new List<String>();
            n.Data = string.Empty;
            n.Data2 = string.Empty;
            int indexOfYourColumn = 9;
            int index2 = 0;
            var restaurantList = new List<Named>();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                n.Data = row.Cells[indexOfYourColumn].Value.ToString();

                if (cell.Value.ToString() == n.Data.ToString())
                {

                    restaurantList.Add(new Nalozi()
                    {
                        Data = row.Cells[indexOfYourColumn].Value.ToString(),
                        Data2 = row.Cells[index2].Value.ToString()
                    });


                }
            }


            dataGridView3.DataSource = restaurantList;
        }


    }
```

So now i just need on buttnClick to show this dataGridView3 in another form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update Datagridview From Another Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887948/update-datagridview-from-another-form)

Comment: why don't you pass your datasource in constructor?

Comment: @learningNew I've tried, but dataGridView shows empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass `DataGridView` from one form to another you might have to pass `DataGridView.DataSource` of `DataGridView` from one Form to other. Something like that

```
new SecondForm(dataGridView.DataSource)
```

and your `SecondForm` will accepts passed `DataSource` and pass that to `DataGridView` of that form

```
class SecondForm
{
    public SecondForm(object dataSource)
    {
        InitializeComponents();

        dataGridView.DataSource = dataSource;
    }
}
```

If you want to pass copy of `DataSource` you can create a new `DataTable` from existing data inside `DataGridView` of `FirstForm`

```
private DataTable GetDataTableFromDGV(DataGridView dgv)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
    {
        if (column.Visible)
        {
            // You could potentially name the column based on the DGV column name (beware of dupes)
            // or assign a type based on the data type of the data bound to this DGV column.
            dt.Columns.Add();
        }
    }

    object[] cellValues = new object[dgv.Columns.Count];
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            cellValues[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(cellValues);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

and update first call to this

```
new SecondForm(GetDataTableFromDGV(dataGridView))
```