# Passing data from datagridview to another

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to pass rows from datagridview to another in same form.I have numericupdown and i want to choose one row and pass it as many as in my numericupdown value. But in second datagridview i only want to show 1 of them.others will be copied to datatable.

I don't know how to do that.Can anyone help me with this problem?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Dgw1.CurrentRow == null)
            return;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Dgw1.SelectedRows)
        {
            ((DataTable)Dgw2.DataSource).ImportRow(((DataRowView)row.DataBoundItem).Row); 

        }


    }
```

Comment: I dont get it right, you want to choose one row in a datagridview and pass it to another datagridview multiple times? and then only show once?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass datagridview from one form to another c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033325/pass-datagridview-from-one-form-to-another-c-sharp)

Comment: i have datatable1.my first datagridview1 datasource = datatable1. datagridview2 = datasource = datatable2.when i am passing rows from dgw1 to dgw2 it also fiil my datatable2.Now i want to pass 1 row multiple times but in my app i want show only one.